# How do you change the text of a progress bar after it has finished updating in Java?

Tags: java, progress-bar

1) Initially I want my progress bar to show the text:
   "Opening..."
   I want this text go away once processing has begun.

2) After progress bar has finished processing I want it to show:
   "Finished.."

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use [`setString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setString(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
progressbar.setString(String);
```

after the progress bar is done loading.

For more on Progress Bars in Java, look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html